# how to add buttons to each page block section in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I have three page block section in a pageblock of the visualforce page. I am using standard controller with extension. I need to add standard save/cancel buttons to first section alone. I can use a different page block for the next two sections. But i want all the sections in one page block and the buttons only to the first section.

Please let me know how to keep the buttons specific to each section.

Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="xxx" extensions="xxxExtension" id="page">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information" collapsible="true" columns="2" id="pbs"> 
            input and output fields 
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 

        <!-- I want the buttons within this section  -->
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Related Events" collapsible="true">
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Other Information" collapsible="true">
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: My code is below <apex:page standardController="xxx" extensions="xxxExtension" id="page">
<apex:pageBlock id="pb">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information" collapsible="true" columns="2" id="pbs">             
            input and output fields         
</apex:pageBlockSection>
// I want the buttons within this section       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Related Events" collapsible="true">
        
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Other Information" collapsible="true">  </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about to use a `apex:pageBlockSectionItem`. You can "group" element with that tag:

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Related Events" collapsible="true" >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" />
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes that can be used. But it does not allow more than two components. In my case i need to add three buttons. Edit, Save and Cancel

Comment: @SFDCLearner Not really correct. You can put multiple elements into the `apex:outputPanel`. I've updated my answer.